# mysql SELECT WHERE and SELECT again

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables Customers and Customer_orders. I'm trying to SELECT customer's order by using Customer_ID from Customer table.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer_orders WHERE Customer_ID = SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE Customer_name = 'John Doe'
```

This code does not work. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select from two tables in MYSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157294/select-from-two-tables-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to JOIN those 2 tables and then query for what you need. Like this:

```
SELECT co.* 
FROM Customer_orders co 
INNER JOIN Customers c ON co.Customer_ID = c.ID 
WHERE c.Customer_name = 'John Doe';
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is a little complex - it might attempt to show you a solution that can solve a more difficult problem.

First, it queries the ID of the John Doe from Customer table.
Second, it queries the all columns from Customer_orders table where customer_id equals ID.

My solution is easy:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer_orders WHERE Customer_ID in (SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE Customer_name = 'John Doe')
or
SELECT * FROM Customer_orders WHERE Customer_ID = (SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE Customer_name = 'John Doe')
```

Generally, ID is a primary key of Customer table and the customer_id should be a key index of the Customer_orders.

Two times query of single table using key index is faster than the query using join operation especially when the tables have too many rows.

And thanks Tim to correct my grammar. I so appreciate it. My English is not good .

Comment: Hi Xiong, welcome to SO. I've suggested an edit to your answer to slightly improve its readability, but there is one thing it's missing: an explanation of why/how your answer solves the problem. [Our help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) offers some advice on writing good answers; do you think you could edit your post to include some additional explanation of your query?

Answer (score 1):

you can use join method (inner / left) or even subquery (but not recommend to use this on this problem)

here example

inner join

```
SELECT cust_order.* FROM Customer_orders cust_order, Customers cust WHERE cust_order.Customer_ID  = cust.ID AND  cust.Customer_name = 'John Doe'
```

left join

```
SELECT cust_order.* FROM Customer_orders cust_order LEFT JOIN Customers cust ON cust_order.Customer_ID  = cust.ID WHERE cust.Customer_name = 'John Doe'
```

sub query

```
SELECT * FROM Customer_orders WHERE Customer_ID   =  (SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE Customer_name = 'John Doe')
```

make sure you only have 1 ID on table Customers if you want to use sub query, or if it have more than 1 ID, you can use "IN" instead of "="